# sqlite query with multiple columns result

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, pivot

I want to take an sqlite data table:

```
Margin  Load  Volt
------  ----  ----
10      1     6.0
15      2     6.0
20      3     6.0
35      1     7.0
45      2     7.0
55      3     7.0
91      3     8.0
92      3     8.0
95      3     8.0
```

and create new table:

```
Load  Margin6  Margin7  Margin8
----  -------  -------  -------
1     10       35       91  
2     15       45       92
3     20       55       95
```

I have no idea how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    load,
    max(case when volt = 6 then margin end) margin6,
    max(case when volt = 7 then margin end) margin7,
    max(case when volt = 8 then margin end) margin8
from mytable
group by load
```

If you want to create a table with the results of the query, an option is to use the `create table ... as select ...` syntax:

```
create table newtable as
select 
    load,
    max(case when volt = 6 then margin end) margin6,
    max(case when volt = 7 then margin end) margin7,
    max(case when volt = 8 then margin end) margin8
from mytable
group by load
```

Also I would not really recommend that, because it does not give you room to define constraints, primary key, and other related meta information. You could as well `create` the table first, and then feed it with an `insert into ... select ...` statement.